# Parse Ajax xml response with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml document with JQuery. The xml is obtained through an Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: address,
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'xml',
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
```

});

If I put the request on the browser, I get a response like this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<root>
  <c>208</c>
    <lst>
      <s>
        <id>92</id>
        <t>3</t>
        <ot>06,00</ot>
        <ct>21,30</ct>
        <cat>Electronics</cat>
      </s>
...
```

Now, I've tried in several ways to parse the xml response, for example I tried to log on the console elements with tag 't', but I didn't succeded.

I tried, into success function:

```
var tag = $(data).find('t');
console.log(tag);
```

but this gives me an empty array

also this solution gives me an empty array:

```
var parser=new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data.responseText,"text/xml");
console.log(xmlDoc);
console.log($(xmlDoc).find('t'));
```

Does anyone know the correct way to parse this xml document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the issue was that I was trying to make a cross-domain XML request in the wrong way. This code is working for me:

```
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + address + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';

    // Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.
    // Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
    $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
        var xml = data.results[0];
        console.log(xml);
        console.log($(xml).find('t')[0].innerHTML);

    });
```

I hope this will help someone else with the same issue